# Is there any to improve the reliability of Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage? It's about as consistant as a cat

Tags: wear-os

Code I'm using:

```
    client.blockingConnect();
    try {
        Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(client, 
                    nodeId, path, message.getBytes("UTF-16"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    client.disconnect();
```

The variables path, and message are strings that contain just what they're named after, and client, and nodeId are set with this code (which with the latest Android Wear release needs to be modified too accommodate multiple devices, but the not the current issue I'm working on):

```
            client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                    .addApi(Wearable.API)
                    .build();

            while (nodeId.length() < 1) {
                client.blockingConnect();
                Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(client).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult nodes) {
                        for (Node node : nodes.getNodes()) {
                            nodeId = node.getId();
                            //nodeName = node.getDisplayName();
                            haveId = true;
                            status = ConnectionStatus.connected;
                        }
                    }
                });
                client.disconnect();
```

The problem I'm having is sometimes it works, sometimes quick, and other times after a long delay, and sometimes not at all. Tides, phase of the moon, humidity, butterflys flapping on the other side of the world, not sure what changes. Android wear reports the device as connected always though. Sometimes the messages are the same values, but still need to be handled separately, because when they happen it's important either the watch or mobile respond.

Is there anyway to improve the reliability?

I've tried:

```
        sendMessage(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()), "wake up!");
```

But that don't go through sometimes either.

Comment: Just to add: I just read that sendMessage can't be ran on the ui thread, however, I'm calling it from a separate thread, so I think that can be ruled out so no one wastes time on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `MessageApi` is inherently unreliable. Think of it as UDP. You can use it if you want to deliver the message fast and you don't mind it will fail, because you can repeat it (for example, user switches track in your music app - either it works, or he will have to press the button again).

If you need reliability, use `DataApi`. It's slower, but has guarantees eventual consistency.

If you want both speed and guaranteed delivery, use both approaches - send both a message and set a data item with the same token. If the message is received, keep the token and ignore the data item later. If not, the data item will finally trigger the action.

**EDIT**
Document states that the messages will be delivered to a node only if the node is connected:

> Messages are delivered to connected network nodes. A message is
>   considered successful if it has been queued for delivery to the
>   specified node. A message will only be queued if the specified node is
>   connected. The DataApi should be used for messages to nodes which are
>   not currently connected (to be delivered on connection).

Comment: Thanks! That clarifies their roles much better.

Comment: @gruszczy: Does it say anywhere on developer documentation that MesageApi is unreliable (by design)? Or is this just an observation?